# Will the Raspberry Pi Camera Board output to the Raspberry Pi 7" DSI Screen when using the picamera library?

Tags: raspicam

I am working on a project that makes use of the Raspberry Pi 2, a Raspery Pi camera board, and I want to output to the official [Raspberry Pi 7" DSI Touch Screen](http://www.newark.com/raspberry-pi/raspberrypi-display/display-7-touch-screen-rpi-sbc/dp/49Y1712?ost=49Y1712&ad=81515566461&selectedCategoryId=&CMP=KNC-GUSA-GEN-SHOPPING-NEW-RASPBERRY-PI&gclid=CIO85qLN3soCFdaRHwodNuEMkQ).

If I use the picamera library, am i correct to assume everything will just work as if I was using an hdmi monitor?

Answer (score 2):

From the picamera [FAQ](https://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.10/faq.html):

> **6.3. The preview doesn’t work on my PiTFT screen**
>
> The camera’s preview system directly overlays the Pi’s output on the
> HDMI or composite video ports. At this time, it will not operate with
> GPIO-driven displays like the PiTFT. Some projects, like the Adafruit
> Touchscreen Camera project, have approximated a preview by rapidly
> capturing unencoded images and displaying them on the PiTFT instead.

Based on this I went ahead and purchased the DSI touch screen.

After receiving the display, I am able to report that everything works as intended.

So the answer to the questions is: YES!